# json_decode is not returning proper php array of api response with curl call

Tags: php, arrays, curl, json

I am working on the shipping API for one of my client. I have the shipping api from the vendor. On making curl request in json format, the json response is not converted into php array? Find the code below:

```
$params['format'] = 'json';
$params['data'] =json_encode($package_data);
$token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$url = "http://test.shipping.co/push/json/?token=".$token;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($params));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);
$results = json_decode($result, true);
print_r($results);
```

Here I have 2 print_r function, and following is the output:

> { "cash_pickups_count": 1.0, "cod_count": 0, "success": true,
>   "package_count": 1, "upload_wbn": "UPL21969440", "replacement_count":
>   0, "cod_amount": 0.0, "prepaid_count": 0, "pickups_count": 0,
>   "packages": [ { "status": "Success", "waybill": "0008110000125",
>   "refnum": "8", "client": "demo", "remarks": "", "cod_amount":
>   21841.0, "payment": "Cash" } ], "cash_pickups": 21841.0 }1
>
> 1

I am receiving 2 output as : 1

I want to access the array in php of this response. I tried json_decode() but it is not responding properly.
Need your inputs here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option. In this case CURL outputs response directly into `STDOUT` (browser) and `curl_exec` returns `true`. Because of this `json_decode` cannot decode `$result` variable (since it has value = `true`).

So you have to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($params));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);
$results = json_decode($result, true);
print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to add this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below one

```
$results = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

instead of

```
$results = json_decode($result, true);
```

Comment: its giving me same error. I am still unable to get the php array. Any other method I can get this response in php and process the results?

Comment: After adding this, only difference in output was that **1** as an output was not coming. Only the response was printed in $results.

Comment: what php version are you using?

Comment: $result = '{ "cash_pickups_count": 1.0, "cod_count": 0, "success": true, "package_count": 1, "upload_wbn": "UPL21969440", "replacement_count": 0, "cod_amount": 0.0, "prepaid_count": 0, "pickups_count": 0, "packages": [ { "status": "Success", "waybill": "0008110000125", "refnum": "8", "client": "demo", "remarks": "", "cod_amount": 21841.0, "payment": "Cash" } ], "cash_pickups": 21841.0 }';
$results = json_decode($result, true);
test this if its not printing desired output than may b you have problem in json_decode function